# Android ADT Eclipse install errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Installed Eclipse and the ADT package, 2.3 SDK etc, but get thrown a whole mess of errors on startup and I need some guidance, my searches haven't found the solution I'm looking for, just single errors as opposed to the entire stack I'm getting.

```
Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView

Could not create the view: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DataSourceExplorerNavigator

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-26 09:45:18.955
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@5a1755b3)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@31fb88fa)}

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-26 09:45:18.957
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.cut: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$CutActionHandler@6e9b8445)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$CutActionHandler@240906be)}

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-26 09:45:18.959
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$CopyActionHandler@493ad9ad)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$CopyActionHandler@36a9126a)}

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-26 09:45:18.961
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$PasteActionHandler@c31132)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler$PasteActionHandler@69dea02)}

**(these go on and on and on)**


!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2013-06-26 09:45:18.345
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.dse/icons/full/cview16/enterprise_explorer.gif".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.dse/icons/full/cview16/enterprise_explorer.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:112)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)

**As do these**
```

I am a complete noob so go easy, I've followed all the install steps I've found and yet to get it working, and can't figure it out on my lonesome.

EDIT:

Reinstalled all of Java. I'm still getting the Conflicting Handlers errors, and have this up permanently "activity_main.xml will refresh automatically once the process is finished."

Comment: Windows 7 64bit - sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: I guess that you may have a corrupted copy.
Try this link to download a zipped copy. Extract it and run it:
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522.zip

Comment: Downloading again for the sake of it, but that's the same source I got my original copy from.

Comment: Same errors with the new download

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: 1.7? I have the latest as far as I know.

Comment: Added an edit to the main post

Comment: I have searched a lot about this issue, looks like Eclipse JUNO is bugged a lot. It was recommended to install another Eclipse, and then add the ADT package to it.....
sorry couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have it pointing at a workspace that has projects in it that were created with an old version of Eclipse. Change the workspace and it should work.